# Is it possible add an id to an element which already has an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was adding a class to an element like this:`.addClass('middle_item')`

Then i notice that class in unique, so i should change it to an id `.attr("id", 'middle_item');`, right?

So, can I add another id to an element which already has an id?

If the answer is yes, theres any way to get and save the first id in a variable?

[Example Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nj3c9aoj/3/)

Comment: There's no particular reason to change a class to an id just because it's the only element with that class. An element can only have one id, but it can have many classes.

Comment: @Pointy i only want to change the class to id, because i learned if only an element can has that class, so that class should be an id

Comment: You should un-learn that notion, because it really makes no sense.

Comment: @Pointy - You should have pointed him to your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005978/javascript-html-using-id-vs-class-when-naming?s=5|0.8140   :)

Comment: @talemyn wow I was on fire that day :)

Comment: Let's hear it for @Pointy everyone!  Tireless answering the same questions over and over again, year after year!   :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not allowed . . . while there are differences between HTML 4 and HTML 5 in regards to "legal ID values", one of the things that they have in common is that spaces are not allowed in the values:

HTML 4 definition - http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

HTML 5 definition - http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.

As such, without spaces, you can only ever have a single ID value.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Pointy said, you can only have 1 ID on an element.  It seems like you are trying to apply an ID or class to the `<li>` in order to grab it later?  If so, there are better ways of getting at the middle item in a list with jQuery using `:nth-child()` selector, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2269052/4904449) post.  Selector documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one `id` per element see [this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192048/can-an-html-element-have-multiple-ids) so you have to remove the previous id but that's weird.

All this considered, here is how you could achieve this but I don't imagine that this is actually what you want

`$("#listitem1").removeAttr("id").attr("id", "newID")`

In the above code I'm chaining the methods by first selecting `#listitem1` then removing it's id attribute and finally applying a new id.

Also in your example `var i = $("middle_item").attr("id");` returns undefined because the id never applied but if you did you made two errors: first you wrote `$("middle_item")` when it should have been `$("#middle_item")` and second because you didn't first remove the previous `id`.

[jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1)

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.